# Script Task deleting folders fails in Deployment stage

Tags: deployment, cmd, bamboo

I try to run the following script in a deployment stage for one of your project. But with no success. The script should delete all folders and all .zip-files starting with *Update* and then copy the new zip to the destination.

**My script:**

```
@echo off
set "pathToCopy=\\{server}\Updates"
set "fileName=Update*.zip"
set "username=user"
set "password=secret"

echo Get network share rights...
net use "%pathToCopy%" /USER:%username% %password%
if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo Network access not possible & exit /b 1

for /D %f in ("%pathToCopy%\Update*") do rmdir %f /S /Q

del "%pathToCopy%\Update_*.zip"

copy "%fileName%" "%pathToCopy%"
```

The `del` and `copy` command are working fine, but the `for` with the `rmdir`does not and I get the following message (SyntaxError)

```
"pathToCopyf" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden. (German)
```

I can run the script using cmd from my local development machine without any problems. I can reproduce this error from my local machine when I run the `for` without `()`

```
for /D %f in "%pathToCopy%\Update*" do rmdir %f /S /Q
```

So, is there a Bug in Bamboo (5.9.3) handling the `for`? 
Do I have to rewrite my `for`? 
What other solutions do I have to delete all folders using a wildcard?

Comment: Your quote marks are incorrect. Use `set pathToCopy="\\{server}\Updates"` but you only need the quotes if you have spaces.

Comment: Also when using batch files you need to escape the % sign with another one. ie `%%f`

Comment: @FloatingKiwi thats it. Fixing `%f` to `%%f` solved my problem. add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal and batch files handle the % sign in 2 different ways.

Although this will work from the terminal:

```
for /D %f in "%pathToCopy%\Update*" do rmdir %f /S /Q
```

% needs to be escaped with another % sign to work from a batch file:

```
for /D %%f in "%pathToCopy%\Update*" do rmdir %%f /S /Q
```